# Error when webservice file included in my project

Tags: asp.net, web-services

In my project, I included Webservice files, when I tried to run, I got this error in Chrome browser.

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

---

> Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Unified.WebService.GetOrder [c:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\417f2571\29df25a\assembly\dl3\1f05470e\0779ccf4_47dfcd01_0\WasteManagement.DLL]' to 'Unified.WebService.GetOrder [c:\Users\Venkatesh\Desktop\Venkateshwar\Company Related\Waste Management - Copy\WasteManagement\WasteManagement\App_Code\GetOrder.cs(8)]'

**Source Error:**

```
 Line 43:         public GetOrder retrieveOrder(string orderNumber)
 Line 44:         {
                        //Calling Web service method in my class
 Line 45:/*ERROR*/      return connection.getOrder(orderNumber);
 Line 46:         }
 Line 47:
```

When I clicked `Compiler Warning Messages`, it is showing error in all the connections which were through Web service.

If necessary, I will share the code too. (As I am new to asp.net, I cant understand which part of code to share. So, please mention which part of code you want, if needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Web-service should be independent project in your solution. After that you should add Web Reference for it, and after that you can safely call it.

Web Service is not a basic class you cann add and use - it is a different thing, so you can't simply add it to your `App_Code` folder to make it work.

From MSDN:

> Web service discovery is the process by which a client locates a Web service and obtains its service description. The process of Web service discovery in Visual Studio involves interrogating a Web site following a predetermined algorithm. The goal of the process is to locate the service description, which is an XML document that uses the Web Services Description Language (WSDL).
>
> The service description describes what services are available and how to interact with those services. **Without a service description, it is impossible to programmatically interact with a Web service.**

**Edit:**

Yes, you can remove `[WebMethod]` attributes, etc, from web service declaration, and temporary use it like class, but after that you still have to add a Web reference for it to use it like Web Service.

Comment: I have not created the Webservice file completely.. so till then I decided to work with keeping it inside my project (as my other colleagues opted for).

Comment: @Mr_Green You still have to add a referenece before using Web Service. This is the only way.

Comment: hmm ok I will take your advice.. I was going the same way before as you explained now.. but when my friends suggested me to do this :). Ok then I will let you know..

Comment: Hey can we do as changing the webservice as a class for temporary time and then after completion of it making it to webservice? no problems right?